# Disabling sidebar in pelican octopress theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, octopress, pelican

Can someone please guide me in disabling sidebar for the entire blog?

The solutions provided on web are for octopress and not for pelican-octopress-theme.

Answer (score 1):

In the `template/base.html`, you have to remove

```
{% include '_includes/sidebar.html' %}
```